# How to add typing hint for lists and numpy arrays of different element types?

Tags: python, numpy, type-hinting

basically I want to add typing hints for my class like following (pseudo code):

```
Vector = List or numpy.ndarray  # a mutable array, but not set
NumericScalar = int or float
SignalDType = NumericScalar, bool or hex 
Signal = List[str]
```

This is the main problem, I don't know how it should be implemented

```
 SignalData = Vector[SignalDType]
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Well, the **or** in your pseudocode can be represented by `typing.Union`. Not entirely sure what `hex` is supposed to mean – probably just a string. You cannot check it only contains hex-characters statically, I believe.
Do you really care what type of iterable is passed?
Otherwise use `typing.Iterable` should be okay.

Comment: With that hex notation you are right. I think that hex signals are even converted to integer format as they are passed to my program, however the dtypes stored under SignalDtype are quite important. The disadvantage of using Iteratarable is that it includes Tuple, Set and Dict as well. I only need List and np.ndarray and store it as a typing hint Vector storing SignalDtype objects